# Sub query in aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server

Example:

Actually a query which repeats

```
    Select Style_Color, Style_Color_Desc, RPT, Weeks, 
      Minimum, 
Max(CASE WHEN Cluster_ID in ('0150') then CAST(c.APS_Dev as decimal(10, 2)) end) AS 'APS Dev'
Max(CASE WHEN Cluster_ID in ('0082') then CAST(c.APS_Dev as decimal(10, 2)) end) AS 'APS Dev'
Max(CASE WHEN Cluster_ID in ('0096') then CAST(c.APS_Dev as decimal(10, 2)) end) AS 'APS Dev'
   From Cluster_Data 
     group by Style_Color, Style_Color_Desc,RPT, Weeks, Minimum
          Order by rpt, Style_Color
```

I would like to replace the code  by sub query in aggregate function

```
  Select Style_Color, Style_Color_Desc, RPT, Weeks, 
      Minimum, 
Max(CASE WHEN Cluster_ID in (Select Cluster_ID From Cluster_Data2) then CAST(c.APS_Dev as decimal(10, 2)) end) as 'APS Dev'

   From Cluster_Data 
     group by Style_Color, Style_Color_Desc, RPT, Weeks, Minimum
          Order by rpt, Style_Color
```

Getting error

> "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
>   aggregate or a subquery"

Comment: Please include sample data, table definitions and expected output in your question

Comment: You have rethink about the implementation of `Max(CASE WHEN Cluster_ID in (Select Cluster_ID From Cluster_Data) then <condition> From Cluster_Data`. That `when` condition will be true for all the cases since both are same tables

Comment: Your sample code makes no sense.  The `cluster_id` is obviously going to be in a list of cluster ids from the same table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the calculation in a subquery:

```
select  ... 
,       max(CASE WHEN IsInData = 1 THEN CAST(c.APS_Dev as decimal(10, 2)) END) as 'APS Dev'
from    (
        select  *
        ,       case when Cluster_ID in (Select Cluster_ID From Cluster_Data) then 1 end
                    as IsInData
        from    Cluster_Data
        ) sub
group by
        ...
```

Note that a `Cluster_ID` from `Cluster_Data` is always in `Cluster_Data`, so your condition is always true.

Comment: I tied this approach but getting error 


"An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'THEN'  "

Comment: Then you're using SQL Server, not MySQL.  SQL Server requires `when <value> = 1 then` instead of `when <value> then`, edited in answer